# What is the difference between a "Chaver" and a regular Friend (Chaver)?

Tags: talmud-gemara

In the gemara it seems to sometimes refer to someone as a Chaver in a halachik sense and other times in a sense of meaning just a friend. What is the difference and how would one delineate between the two? Are there sources in the Talmud that explain the difference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaber

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really help. There are limited references and I need something concrete for the research! Thanks again!

Comment: Can you bring examples in the _Gemara_ where _Chaver_ isn't used in the _Halakhic_ sense (especially where it's not obvious from the context what is meant)?